# How can I access an angular service inside a Guard?

Tags: angular, http

I have an Angular Service that checks if my client has a valid http-only JWT Cookie. Since I cannot access this cookie from the client I need to call the service method in my Guard to send a call to the server and see if my user is authenticated. The only problem is that I have no idea how I should get an instance of the service inside the Guard

The code I have written so far:

My guard (or at least what it should do):

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

      let isAuthenticated : boolean = false;
      
      auth: AuthService = new AuthService()
      this.auth.getAuthStatus()
      .subscribe({
        res => {
          if(res.status == 200){
            isAuthenticated = true;
          }
        }
      });

      return isAuthenticated;
  }
}
```

My service:

```
export class AuthService{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAuthStatus(): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>{
    return this.http.post(environment.server + environment.routes.authRoutes.status, "", {
      withCredentials: true,
      observe: 'response'
    })
  }
}
```

I know that I somehow need to get an instance of the http service but I dont think getting a new instance every time is a good idea. I would like to create an instance of the service once and then use it, or make it static so i dont need instances at all. What would be the best solution to this?

Comment: Why not use dependency injection, as you do to get an `HttpClient` instance in the `AuthService`?

Comment: I have no idea what I did in case I used dependency injection. I know that sounds bad, and it probably is, I will look it up, but could you elaborate further?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Put that as a formal answer and I'd upvote it.  I'm curious if Kleecarim tried that and what errors he ran into.

Comment: Again it's what you're _already doing_ in the `AuthService`. It's one of the major features of the framework you're using: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection. It's also covered in the tutorial, which I'd strongly recommend running through: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4.

Comment: Oh, okay. I see what you mean. Either I dont understand it properly, or I just didnt hear anyone call it that before. In case you mean adding it to the constructor, I tried that and I got an error but since it looks like this is the way to go I will try to make it work now

@JeffryHouser I already tried that, but I got the error "property <MyServiceInstance> does not exist on type <MyGuard>"

edit: I for some reason it does not work when I dont add an access modifier, but now it works

Comment: The access modifier is needed to make it a [parameter property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties). It's helpful to show what you've tried and the specific errors when you ask a question.

Comment: thank you, I will update my questiont to help anyone who runs into the same issue in the future. I have another question though, if you do not mind: since .subscribe is running asynchronously, my guard always returns the default value of the variable I return. I tried returning a promise but it still does not work

Comment: That's a separate question, and should be researched (then, if still necessary, asked) separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply just inject it using the constructor

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
     
    // use 'this.authService.whatever()'

  }
}
```

If you want a single instance of any service that will be available everywhere in your app.

Otherwise known as a *[Singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)*.

You can simply add this to the services class:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyServiceClass...
```

A singleton service is a service for which only one instance exists in an application.

Comment: Oh, okay. thank you. It seems like I dont understand Angular dependency injection correctly, I will look into that

Comment: Please consider marking this as the accepted answer if it resolved your issue so others can benefit from it as well

Comment: Sure,I forgot to do that, my bad. Thank you again